# If $n$ is odd prove that $D_{2n} \cong \langle a^n \rangle \times \langle a^2,b\rangle.$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, dihedral-groups, direct-product

Let

$$D_{n}=\langle a,b\mid abab,b^2,a^n \rangle$$be the $n$th dihedral group. If $n$ is odd prove that $D_{2n} \cong \langle a^n \rangle \times \langle a^2,b\rangle.$

My solution:

First of all $|D_{2n}|=4n.$

$$\tilde{f} :  F_{\{a^2,b\}} \to D_{2n}$$

\begin{array}{ccc}
a^2 & \mapsto & r\\
b & \mapsto & s\\
\{a^2,b\} & \rightarrow & D_{2n}\\
\downarrow & \underset{\tilde{f}}{\nearrow}\\
F_{\{a^2,b\}}
\end{array}

$\tilde{f} $ homomorphism is surjective because $r$ and $s$ generate $D_{2n}$.

Each element of $G$ is represented by one of the following elements:
$(1,1),(1,a^2),(1,a^4) \cdots (1,a^{2n-2}),(1,b),(1,a^2b) \cdots (1,a^{2n-2}b)$
$(a^n,1),(a^n,a^2),(a^n,a^4) \cdots (a^n,a^{2n-2}),(a^n,b),(a^n,a^2b) \cdots (a^n,a^{2n-2}b)$

Exactly $4n$ elements so $\tilde{f} $ is injective.

I am really not sure in my $\tilde{f} $ and in my basis, I'd be grateful for some feedback.

Comment: It looks okay to me. I haven't given it much thought though . . .